# Cannot apply the same measure calculation to find out the previous week value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have written a measure to find out the percentage of the products which are missing. Below is the measure which I have written

`Percentage of missing product = Coalesce(DIVIDE( CALCULATE( DISTINCTCOUNT('Table 1'[ID]), FILTER('Table 1', Table 1 [Missing_Check] = 1)), CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Table 1'[ID]),0)`

The above measure will interact with the Weekly snapshot slicer. Below is the sample data for the data slicer, which is of type text. If I click any of the weekly snapshot below, the above measure will give the percentage for that particular week. This is working perfectly fine.

[image: Weekly snapshot Date slicer- screenshot]

My Question is, I want to compare the present week percentage value with the previous week percentage value based on the selection.

Considering if I select any of the above weekly snapshot, I should get the respective percentage of that week [In a card visual] and in the new measure [another card visual]which we are going to write should display the percentage of the previous week based on the that selection.

I tried to write, but somehow it's not working properly. For example if I select a date 4/24/2023 the 1st card is showing 20% then the second card should show the value of the previous week which is some percentage say 30%. And in the data we have week number as well, See below screenshot

[image: Week number(one of a column in data) screenshot]

Can anyone help me with the new measure please?

Answer (score 0):

DAX [time-intelligence functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/time-intelligence-functions-dax) allows you to manipulate the time period over which an expression is calculated.

`DATEADD()` shifts the date values passed to it by a set interval. In our case, we just want to shift by 7 days backwards.

```
Prior Week Percentage of missing product = 
CALCULATE(
    [Percentage of missing product],
    DATEADD( 'Calendar'[Date], -7, DAY )
)
```

Comment: Hi @luke_0, please not that the date slicer used is of type 'text' since we have a data 'today' in the column. So there is an error while executing the above measure

Comment: Do you have a separate column on your date table with a date/time data type that you can reference instead with this measure? What I've often done in these scenarios with custom labels is to reference my main date/time type column in the measure, and use the text type column in the slicer. The text slicer will still filter your calendar table and the date/time column so the measure will still work.

Comment: yes, I have a calendar table which is a summarize table form the table used in this measure only, which has the date column to be date/time datatype and date slicer column(snap shot date) which is of type text and week number as well. can you give the based on this?

Comment: If I do the same thing as you have mentioned in your measure, it is giving me the same value for both KPI's

Comment: Just use the date type column in the formula where it says `'Calendar'[Date]'`.